# CPLEX quadratic simplex?

Tags: optimization, quadratic, cplex

Does anybody know which simplex-like algorithm CPLEX uses to solve quadratic programs. what is the so called Quadratic Simplex it is using?

Thank you in advance,
Mehdi

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what CPLEX uses but the Simplex Method has been modified by Philip Wolfe to solve quadratic programming. In a nut shell, this is what it does:

Given a quadratic programming problem: QPP. p'x + 1/2x'Cx with constrains Ax = b

1. C has to be symmetric positive definite (positive semi-definite might work as well)
2. generate linear constraints using the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions
3. modify the Simplex method in a way such that complementary slackness holds when choosing the pivot columns.
4. proceed with the other usual Simplex method steps

For more detailed information, please take a look at this paper:
http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~brecht/cs838docs/wolfe-qp.pdf

Hope this helps.